# Connecting asp.net Identity to SQL Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

It seems MVC 5 no longer uses simple membership and I am having trouble figuring out how to use a SQL Azure database instead of the default .mdf file that is generated and saved on the web server. In simple membership it was as easy as changing two connection strings but that does not seem to be the case here. From what I have found online, it seems like I have to create my own custom storage provider to accomplish such a simple task. The only examples and docs I find online that deal with Azure are scenarios in which the developer wants to store in a non-relational setup or Azure Table storage.

Am I right in the above conclusion or is there something I am missing about integrating SQL Azure DB into my MVC 5 Asp.Net Identity app?

Comment: Your connection string is stored in Web.config in the root of the project, and you can most definitely use a relational database. Maybe these free PluralSight videos will help.  http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Identity running on top of a SQL Azure DB in one of my projects. You don't need to implement your own storage provider. The only thing you have to do is to change the connection string (normally named **DefaultConnection**) in your web.config file and point it to your SQL Azure DB.

Comment: That's what I have done but it fails to create any of the additional tables `UserClaims`, `UserLogins`, and `Roles`. Perhaps maybe I should use the direct connection string rather than the entity framework project that I have referencing the SQL Azure dB?

Comment: All others tables are created? How do you handle your connection string? Is it in a separate project? Does this project contain Identity and its context?

Comment: Yes exactly. A separate project in my solution holds the entity framework code itself. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by Identity. I have been trying to trouble shoot my situation and have ended up creating a connection to my sql azure db via the server explorer and taking the generated connection string to paste it into my web.config. As far as I can see the website is connecting to the db but the additional required tables are not being generated. Connection string looks like this.

Comment: `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myservername;Initial Catalog=JdmXchangeProd;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: I am going to create a stock mvc site as a sample and see exactly how the db gets set up and necessary tables generated.

Comment: Ok, seems not to be a problem with your database connection. By Identity I mean ASP.NET Identity. What does your IdentityContext-derived class looks like? As a reference you could create a unchanged project in Visual Studio which uses Identity. You should concentrate on comparing the classes which uses Entity Framework (especially the class which derives from IdentityContext). With a newly created project connecting to Azure SQL DB should be/is as simple as changing the connection string.

Comment: Maybe going through [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) helps you solving your problem.